# Best approach to PageController / custom navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm developing an app that'll follow Google's Material design. I need the top image (kind of custom NavigationBar, not using NavigationController) to fade over to a new image when I swipe sideways across the screen like a PageController, while at the same time fading and sliding a new title label on top of that custom navigationbar background image.

I can animate using this code, but that is ran by a button press or similar, how can I make this synchronized with the finger swiping?

```
    // Fade and slide title and image
myTitleLabelConstraint.constant = myTitleLabelConstraint.constant - 20;
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:1.0 initialSpringVelocity:1.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
    // Animate
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    myTitleLabel.alpha = 1;
    topImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_navBar.png"];
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Complete
}];
```

I need this to happen as well as swiping between 3 ViewControllers - 2 UIViewControllers and 1 UITableViewController. I was thinking of using a container that hosts a PageController - is this a good solution?

I've looked at [this](http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168) tutorial but I find it hard to understand what he actually means. Scrollview - why use that?

**So my question summarized is as follows:** how can I animate the label and background image of my custom navigationbar synchronized with the user's touches while animating between the 3 ViewControllers with or without a PageController (with PageController physics atleast)?

Thanks a lot for help on this!

**UPDATE**

This is how my StoryBoard looks right now:

[image]

**A closer look:**

[image]

The left ViewController is the "host" containing 3 Containers whereas each of those three containers are linked to one of the ViewControllers on the right.

Best Regards,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into interactive transitions in iOS. If you look up `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransitions` (introduced in iOS 7) that should give you exactly what you need. You more or less have the animation code already, and `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransitions` allow to you wire a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your animation to scrub through each animation frame. Here is a very good [blog](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-transitions/) that teaches how to do this.

Comment: I see, that looks like a viable solution. How's memory management with this approach? If I'm not using PageController, wouldn't the off-screen ViewControllers draw unnecessary system resources? Also, how can I apply physics to the VC management, so that a VC would snap back into place when the user lifts his/her finger like a PageController would normally manage?

Comment: Memory management is pretty good actually. Lifting a finger in that case should be a simple matter of calling finishInteractiveTransition and cancelInteractiveTransition or something like that.

Comment: Then it looks like a really good solution. When it comes to placing the viewcontrollers - can I create 3 UIViewControllers and wire them up to 3 containerviews which I will place like so [VC2-VC1-VC3] on the main/host viewcontroller? Whereas VC2 and VC3 is off-screen?

Comment: Well, the interactive transition should be thought of like that of a regular push from a UINavigationController. On the start of the interactive transition, you build up your next VC and supply the transition object the animation block to occur between the two VCs. Wiring them up in storyboard may not be the best approach since you would have to build up your VCs at the start of your transition.

Comment: If you really want to have a transition that takes advantage of the spring animation/damping physics that is interactive, you would want to go with this approach since Cocoa will break down the frames of the transition and scrub through them with the interactive transition.

Comment: I don't understand how to build the connection between the ViewControllers with this approach. Should I instantiate them with code or use a Container? Could you please elaborate and explain?:) - See my updated question for my current StoryBoard setup